# How to write a query:"if does not exist, then insert the rows that does not exist" with only foreign key to the third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables:

Resource table: ResourceID, ResourceValue, ProjectName

Translation table: ResourceID, translatedValue, language.(This is the table to save all the current Translation for resourceValue. Basically one resourceValue from resource table will translate to multiple language version and insert to this table.)

TranslationPool: ResourceValue, TranslatedValue, language.(This is a pool to save all types of translation for the resourceValue, may or may not in use)

I want to write a stored procedure in SQL server, the parameter is a projectName, it will check if all the resourceValue under that projectName to see if they have translation in Translation table, for all the resourceValue that does not have a translation in Translation table, insert the respect translation from TranslationPool.

I know I need to use merge clause for this, but I don't know how to write a merge clause that involves 3 tables, because I want to insert the all the translation that non exists in Translation table from TranslationPool, but they are not directly connected by a foreign key.

Comment: You don't need a Merge clause, you can do this with OUTER JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a head start. You don't even need any `merge` or `join` and you still achieve it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure
@projectName VARCHAR(100) --Input from the user

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
@totalRows INT

--What happen is, if the resourceValue is already existed in the Translation_table,
--it will return count more than 0
SET @totalRows = (SELECT count(resourceValue) FROM Translation_table WHERE resourceValue = @projectName)

--And if that happen, you can simply display some message saying that the resourceValue  has already existed
IF (@totalRows > 0)
BEGIN   
--Already exist
END

--If the count is 0, meaning there is nothing, then you will "copy" from the Pool
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Translation_table
SELECT FROM TranslationPool WHERE resourceValue = @projectName
END

END
```

Comment: Why would you expect resourceValue to equal projectName?   They are separate columns in his table.   Also the Translation table doesn't have a resourceValue column.

Comment: The OP did not mention which field is for what, so I'm just assuming it. In any case, my solution is just a sample to give an idea to OP on how he/she may solve the problem